# Using `std::sort` with a member function in a templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, function-pointers, typedef

The problem I'm having is that I want to use STL's sort with a custom compare function inside a templated class.

The idea from using typedef came from another [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278635/using-stl-algorithms-specifically-stdsort-from-within-a-templated-class)

Anyway, here is the code:

```
template <typename R,typename S>
class mesh{
  /* some stuff */

  void sortData(){
    typedef bool (*comparer_t)(const S,const S);
    comparer_t cmp = &mesh::compareEdgesFromIndex;
    sort(indx,indx+sides*eSize,cmp);
  }

  /* more stuff */

  // eData and cIndx are member variables
  bool compareEdgesFromIndex(const S a,const S b){
    return compareEdges(eData[cIndx[2*a]],eData[cIndx[2*a+1]],eData[cIndx[2*b]],eData[cIndx[2*b+1]]); 
  }
};
```

The error I'm getting is

```
mesh.h:130:29: error: cannot convert ‘bool (mesh<float, unsigned int>::*)(unsigned int, unsigned int)’ to ‘comparer_t {aka\
bool (*)(unsigned int, unsigned int)}’ in initialization
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to mix a *member-function-pointer* where a *function-pointer* is required. You can either refactor the predicate to be a `static` function, or use *bindings* to associate your *member-function-pointer* with an instance of your class `mesh`.

In order to bind an instance to your *member-function-pointer* you would do

```
std::bind( mesh_instance, &mesh::compareEdgesFromIndex, _1, _2 )
```

if working with **C++11**. If you don't have the luxury, then you can use equivalent functionality from *Boost* (replacing `std::bind` by `boost::bind`). **C++03** offers some binding functionality but it's limited, and I believe *obsoleted* now that generic binding functionality is available.

Comment: Sorry for being a newbie, how would the second option be implemented?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare `compareEdgesFromIndex` as static:

```
static bool compareEdgesFromIndex(const S a,const S b){
  return compareEdges(eData[cIndx[2*a]],eData[cIndx[2*a+1]],eData[cIndx[2*b]],eData[cIndx[2*b+1]]); 
}
```

Assuming `compareEdges` is also static. Otherwise you have a member function pointer, which requires a `mesh` pointer to be called.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
When declaring both as static, I get an error saying the use of eData and cIndx is invalid

Comment: You should read about what is a static member function. You will obviously have to modify your code so it doesn't depend on instance variables, since your methods will be static(which means it's somehow a "global function"). My answer just fixes your error message :D.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you wish to use compareEdgesFromIndex as non-static member function, you could pass `boost::bind(this, &mesh::compareEdgesFromIndex, _1, _2)` as comparator.

Comment: I don't have the boost library, but I will try it.
Thank you for the reply!

Comment: You're welcome. You could find boost libraries on boost.org. It's cross-platform and prebuild packages are available for a variety of operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

A member function is not a function because to work it also needs to know which is the object instance being acted on. A **static** member is basically instead just a regular global function with a funny name and the permission to access to private parts of the class.

Indeed a pointer to a non-static member function is not something that you can simply call, but something that you can provide an object instance to get something you can call.

You can instead pass `std::sort` an **object instance** of a class that implements an `::operator()(int, int)` that given two indexes will return the desired result. Unfortunately for reasons I never understood in C++ this object class must be a non-local class because local classes cannot be used in templates (it can be a class defined inside another class, but not a class defined inside a function or method).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `std::bind`, you could use a lambda, which I prefer, because I can never remember the syntax for `std::bind`.

```
auto cmp = [&mesh_instance](unsigned lhs, unsigned rhs) {
    return mesh_instance.compareEdgesFromIndex(lhs, rhs);
};
```